# Интервал ListRow в Leaback

Tags: android, leanback

Использую leanback библиотеку, как изменить отступ слева при построении рядов (ListRow)?

[image: o]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я нашел, где я могу редактировать отступы на ListRow.

Идем в тему вашей активити и добавляем элемент

```
<item name="rowHorizontalGridStyle">@style/CustomHorizontalGridView</item>
```

И в стиле **CustomHorHorizontalGridView** можно редактировать отступы

```
<style name="HorizontalGridView">
<item name="android:focusable">true</item>
<item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>

<item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/content_padding_horizontal</item>
<item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/content_padding_horizontal</item>

<item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing</item>
<item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing</item>
<item name="android:horizontalSpacing">@dimen/lb_browse_item_horizontal_spacing</item>
<item name="android:verticalSpacing">@dimen/lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing</item>
<item name="focusOutFront">true</item>
```